# How to post Data using API with modal class in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to post data in Post Method Through API with using Modal class in flutter. how to post data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[You can go through this official flutter website](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Answer image]

Click on </> button and postman will give you list of options to convert your request into different languages you can select Dart and copy paste the code on your ide and it run the application