# Empty response in API from Dio.Post method in Flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, http, dart, dio

I have been trying to connect to a local Node JS API using Flutter Web. I am using the Dio dart Package with a GET and a POST method, however, the response of my POST method does not return anything. See below a few instances of code and what I am seeing:

On my Node JS app I am receiving information from flutter:

```
'Server is listening on port 8000'
Successfully connected
/login2
{}
```

The `/login2` path and the `{}` are a `console.log` in my API from the Flutter incoming data. See now the Dio.post method:

```
    Future post(String path, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    
    try {
      final result = await _dio.post(path, data: data);
      return result.data;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw ('Error en el POST');
    }
  }
```

Also tried with HTTP, heres the piece of code:

```
Future post2(String id, String password) async {
    print(id);
    print(password);

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/login2'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode({'user': id, 'password': password}),
    );
    print(response);
  }
```

I have tried with Postman and this is what I get:

```
/login2?user=10002&password=123456
{ user: '10002', password: '123456' }
```

That is both the `path` and the query `{}` from the same `console.log` that is empty from Flutter, meaning that my Node server is indeed receiving data.

Trying as per @Wali Kan suggestion with the Postman configuration:

```
Future post(String path, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    final String formData = data.toString();

    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'};
    var request =
        http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000' + path));
    request.body = formData;

    print(request.body);
    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    print(response);

    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
```

Still receiving `/login2` and `{}` on the API side.

What I am missing is how to succesfully receive Flutter data so that I can complete the login process on my Node API and then redirect to the user profile page.

Any recommendations on what to test or check? If you need me to share any more pieces of the code let me know, been stuck here for many hours now... Thank you for your time.

Comment: why are you using dio, you can do it with http

Comment: Tried it with HTTP, editing the question and addint the code now.

Comment: goto this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/69090644/13823875 and check out my answer.

Comment: I will be cheking it, will let you know if it worked

Comment: Tried your solution, still receiving emtpy @WaliKhan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**headers**

```
HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: "json/application/json",
HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

make sure not to use `FormData.fromMap({})` just send your data as normal object and don't forget to include the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type in your headers.
in case your server is running express make sure you have these middleware before processing the request

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]